# preserve name of list element when saving using mapply

Tags: r, lapply, mapply

I'm using `mapply()` to save elements from a list in separate files. E.g.

```
file.names <- c('~/a.RData', '~/b.RData')
data.list <- list(foo = c(1:10), bar = rep(1, 10))

mapply(function(x, y) save(x, file = y), data.list, file.names)
```

and I'd like to be able to call the elements by their original name after loading them again. Now I get

```
load('~/a.RData')
ls()
"x"
```

but I'd like to get

```
load('~/a.RData')
ls()
"foo"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my try:

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) {
  assign(y,x)
  save(list=y,file=z)
}, data.list, names(data.list), file.names)
```

Let's check the output:

```
#rm(list=ls())
load('~/a.RData')
ls()
#[1] "foo"

load('~/b.RData')
ls()
[1] "bar" "foo"

foo
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
bar
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Good question, and this is probably not the ideal answer.  Anyway, one possibility is to use the list as an environment and couple that with the `list` argument in `save()`. The key here is to get the ordering right, as `ls()` orders its output. `with()` creates an environment from the list, so we can use the `list` argument easily.

```
with(data.list, {
    mapply(
        function(x, y) save(list = x, file = y),
        ls()[order(names(data.list))], 
        file.names
    )
})
# $foo
# NULL
#
# $bar
# NULL
```

Check:

```
load('~/a.RData')
ls()
# [1] "data.list"  "f"          "file.names" "foo"       
load('~/b.RData')
ls()
# [1] "bar"        "data.list"  "f"          "file.names" "foo"     
foo
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
bar
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```